# Attach SQL Server 2000 database on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I had MDf Files created with SQL Server 2000 can I attach them on SQL Server 2005 without any problems?

Please anyone advise me.

Comment: Yes, the route up in versions (from 2000 to 2005, from 2005 to 2008 etc.) works just fine, no problem at all. You **cannot** under any circumstances move a database down, however - you cannot attach a database from SQL Server 2005 in a SQL Server 2000 environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll work fine, I've done this a couple of times without any problems.

Just remember if you want to use SQL2005's features on the database, change the compatibility mode from 80 to 90 under the database properties after you attach it.

To do this once the database is running, right-click it, go to "Properties", then click the "Options" menu item on the left, and "Compatibility Level" will appear.

Running the script below will also work.

```
ALTER DATABASE [Your_Db] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

Comment: how can I do changing the compatibility mode from 80 to 90 under the database properties ?